# show date in correct format angular

Tags: node.js, angular, angularjs, multidimensional-array, angular-material

I am making an application in which I want user to submit date date is getting stored in database in this format **2003-06-01T00:00:00.000+00:00** I want to display it as 01/06/2003 or 1st June 2003 can any body help me how can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular date pipe
https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

```
<span>{{startDate | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</span>
```

Comment: do you have any idea how to use it?

Comment: Read this https://angular.io/guide/pipes

Answer (score 0):

You could use date pipe to format your standard ISO date in html template. Find the date object from your template, wrap the value in `{{}}` and then add `| date` pipe to format it. https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

```html
    <td>{{date}} </td>
    <td>yyyy-MM-dd</td>
    <td>{{date | localDate:'yyyy-MM-dd' }}</td>
    <td>{{date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</td>
```

Here is a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-local-date-pipe-bu2nxp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

I have created a small stackblitz for this. You can see date being formatted 4 different ways here:

1. Plain old javascript date
2. Formatted Javascript Date
3. Using Angular Pipe in HTML file
4. Using formateDate() function in component.ts file.

Please refer to this link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cue9h6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html